# Slow SQL in large table, filter by timestamps(int12)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with slow query, making a "simple" select.. i don't understand what is the problem... it's a big table.. but it's a simple query..

The tables:

```
business: (1.000.000 reg)
id (INDEX PRIMARY INT(11) UNSIGNED)
active (INDEX TINYINT(1))

products: (32.000.000 reg)
id (INDEX PRIMARY INT(11) UNSIGNED)
business_id (INDEX INT(11) UNSIGNED)
offer_start (INDEX INT(12) UNSIGNED) (timestam unix)
offer_end (INDEX INT(12) UNSIGNED) (timestamp unix)
price_offer (VARCHAR(10)) (price with decimals)
active (INDEX TINYINT(1))
```

business.id, products.id, products.offer_start and products.offer_end are INDEX (separated)

When I make this:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM products 
LEFT JOIN business ON business.id = products.business_id 
WHERE
 (business.active = '1' AND business.paylimit > 1314029906) 
AND 
 (products.active = '1' AND products.offer_start < 1314029906 AND products.offer_end > 1314029906 AND products.price_offer > 0) 
LIMIT 0,10
```

Take 21 Seconds.
The problem is this: `products.offer_start < 1314029906 AND products.offer_end > 1314029906` takes ~20 seconds to give me results

Is it possible to make this query, filtering other forms to speed up?

Comment: Could you provide explain plan?

Comment: You also are probaly getting the wrong answer. WHERE  (business.active = '1' AND business.paylimit > 1314029906) would change the left join to an inner join since it must meet that criteria.

Comment: What is the exact index on offer_start and offer_end? Are they two separate indexes? Do the index include any other columns?

Answer (score 2):

Some notes about your table schema:

1. offer_start (INDEX INT(12) UNSIGNED) - 12 doesn't make sense because the max symbols in INT is 11. The same for offer_end
2. active (INDEX TINYINT(1)) - index is useless because of cardinality on 1000000 will be 2 - 1 or 0
3. price_offer (VARCHAR(10)) - you can use float or decimal for this one. products.price_offer > 0 will work faster.

Comment: Never use floating point values for prices, decimal is the proper type here

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM products 
    LEFT JOIN business ON business.id = products.business_id 
WHERE business.paylimit > 1314029906
    AND products.offer_start < 1314029906
    AND products.offer_end > 1314029906
    AND products.price_offer > 0
    AND business.active = '1'
LIMIT 0,10
```

MySQL processes filters from left to right so make sure that the condition that is the most selective (returns the least rows) is on the left. Having `business.active = '1'` on the leftmost side of a condition *may* use an index, but if it's selectivity is 50% then the rest of the condition doesn't use an index.

You may want to read [How MySQL Uses Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-indexes.html) in the manual.

Edit:
A short explanation on how MySQL uses indexes: [3 ways MySQL uses indexes](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/09/12/3-ways-mysql-uses-indexes/)